# EditText event propagation

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

I have a custom view and EditText element in my relative layout, i can't receive touch events in my custom view, how can i propagate touch events to my custom view;

My layout looks like ;

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white" >

    <com.test.ui.CustomView
        android:id="@+id/noteView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etPageInput"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="top" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I add touch listener to my EditText and Custom view as like ;

```
    EditText pageInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPageInput);
    pageInput.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            return false;
        }
    });

    CustomView pageView = (CustomView) findViewById(R.id.noteView);
    pageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            System.out.println("Touch event received by custom view !!!")
            return true;
        }
    });
```

I'm not able to receive touch events in my CustomView, any idea what am i missing ?

Answer (score 0):

try to set clickable as true in xml for your custom view
and
try to setonclicklisener

Comment: I guess you didn't get what i mean, i don't care about click events i just need to receive touch events on my CustomView, also AFAIK, touch event listener works before than click listener! You suggestion will not change anything. Thanks...

Comment: have u tried to set clickable as true with your touch event

Comment: what is extends in your customview ?

Comment: Android.view.View; as like, public class CustomView extends View { ... }